# php_smtp dll file doesn't exist

Tags: php, smtp

I am new to php and I am working on a website, I want to send an email from localhost, I am following steps from a youtube tutorial, I reached a point that the `file php_smtp.dll` doesn't exist in the directory `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`

Can anyone tell me how to get this file in order to be able to send mails from local?

Comment: what tutorial? it sounds wrong

Comment: thank you, I have installed it from crome

Comment: um i dont think you understood the question

Comment: sorry, it is right, I didn't understand the question? would you please explain it?